# What's the difference between javafx SelectionMode Single and Multiple?

Tags: java, javafx

When dealing with a ListView, for example, there is a way to define its selection mode, just like this:

```
ListView lstV = new ListView();

lstV.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(a));
lstV.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

I've noticed that there is one more SelectionMode - Single - yet I tried them both and didn't notice any difference. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionMode.html) "Allows for one or more contiguous range of indices to be selected at a time." Try <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> clicking multiple items to see the effect. In contrast, `SelectionMode.SINGLE`, precludes multiple selection.